# Python convert a list of ips into a list of networks

Tags: python, ip-address

I have a list of ips like this;

```
ban = ['162.210.197.58', '36.72.31.198', '163.172.221.63', '134.35.42.49', '176.65.117.81', '46.8.28.110', '110.139.16.72', '31.29.61.218', '38.95.109.67', '31.155.204.143', '5.254.65.190', '46.101.127.145', '111.15.193.84', '187.142.198.151', '188.227.45.110', '125.236.168.242', '5.254.65.122', '5.254.65.28', '185.182.81.93', '188.210.133.199', '151.241.125.237', '207.148.111.126', '145.239.70.231', '2.94.113.65', '204.85.191.30', '2.229.128.135', '92.127.255.182', '46.133.77.143', '118.69.63.15', '46.39.55.162', '185.182.81.14', '188.244.132.49', '138.197.160.121', '176.15.222.56', '82.178.233.175', '94.41.43.252', '78.137.73.171', '5.142.90.22', '212.2.212.151', '207.244.77.174', '176.59.46.108', '179.7.106.194', '154.118.17.57', '5.254.65.119', '176.33.236.247', '41.218.215.25', '199.249.224.47', '207.244.83.97', '84.241.13.93', '197.210.54.218', '93.35.166.148', '218.107.49.9', '39.55.130.71', '78.168.207.252', '213.141.227.238', '36.69.70.20', '5.254.65.218', '103.10.197.12', '207.244.83.194', '122.163.128.154', '93.185.16.82', '95.24.168.216', '103.16.26.148', '118.100.59.199', '209.59.188.147', '207.244.93.234', '88.81.46.212', '23.105.140.146', '89.104.104.225', '83.149.21.13', '41.34.51.195', '146.185.133.214', '37.204.108.198', '188.123.231.194', '85.140.3.172', '185.182.81.45', '185.182.81.61', '5.254.65.213', '185.182.81.136', '103.10.197.205', '185.182.81.86', '207.244.79.138', '116.240.84.42', '91.219.101.68', '80.191.221.23', '178.62.220.63', '209.58.148.85', '167.114.159.186', '108.59.8.246', '74.82.17.84', '178.129.172.216', '36.72.178.137', '41.254.7.157', '185.190.241.83', '185.182.81.58', '107.77.209.79', '207.244.77.137', '58.27.54.130', '69.15.118.106', '85.94.0.117', '41.215.173.28', '185.182.81.28', '46.101.18.209', '5.254.65.185', '195.123.217.178', '2.48.190.213', '188.247.190.79', '192.119.160.190', '95.72.13.156', '68.149.146.193', '197.157.244.206', '103.10.197.157', '176.195.155.114', '194.88.107.55', '83.220.237.120', '185.182.81.53', '82.102.21.114', '84.241.6.212', '207.244.78.48', '125.238.220.170', '159.8.170.20', '176.15.60.114', '46.138.146.207', '128.199.201.63', '5.254.65.179', '45.242.236.151', '188.162.177.199', '186.68.202.84', '5.202.179.40', '41.215.173.10', '103.255.6.80', '83.102.219.15', '188.32.127.17', '185.182.81.89', '207.244.86.235', '212.252.141.6', '37.147.79.146', '176.59.80.125', '212.71.255.8', '87.240.26.58', '91.79.215.243', '185.182.81.6', '207.244.83.102', '185.182.81.20', '109.133.114.88', '199.249.223.78', '37.110.94.227', '185.182.81.42', '109.252.76.194', '167.99.46.145', '95.221.186.30', '185.48.188.131', '2.191.41.213', '82.113.106.115', '178.62.102.23', '197.255.118.226', '185.182.81.12', '41.207.5.116', '68.133.80.56', '103.255.7.6', '162.210.197.53', '138.197.174.120', '185.182.81.40', '154.124.87.182', '73.218.73.13', '185.182.81.66', '139.5.231.112', '185.69.124.60', '93.190.177.36', '207.244.79.136', '66.160.199.70', '78.106.211.173', '121.52.156.4', '109.201.133.100', '78.85.40.39', '91.79.162.72', '83.242.238.138', '5.254.65.125', '5.254.65.175', '103.214.2.4', '37.232.192.102', '61.5.58.240', '41.190.14.40', '146.185.157.250', '195.123.225.47', '103.60.210.61', '85.102.111.101', '77.30.202.151', '194.146.149.46', '95.27.45.39', '146.185.158.24', '207.244.86.240', '195.175.45.154', '195.149.108.48', '95.12.119.124', '82.102.31.203', '156.221.118.172', '78.108.178.87', '185.182.81.37', '41.219.31.245', '191.43.27.200', '142.44.210.125', '5.254.65.169', '46.196.145.191', '68.133.80.55', '5.254.65.127', '68.133.80.58', '31.173.84.201', '39.50.173.251', '46.242.10.175', '201.208.20.239', '174.16.34.27', '65.19.167.132', '182.0.139.135', '128.68.185.234', '78.178.85.114', '182.182.91.44', '103.10.197.155', '199.249.223.77', '46.173.75.34', '197.32.29.188', '185.18.46.170', '107.181.182.227', '105.50.114.109', '199.87.154.255', '185.182.81.23', '5.115.181.178', '67.205.137.158', '46.73.40.13', '117.224.14.73', '155.239.150.15', '98.253.130.3', '122.129.77.114', '176.194.163.88', '109.63.235.0', '85.140.7.208', '207.244.82.229', '94.29.124.69', '188.245.245.146', '78.177.102.153', '197.210.173.174', '85.174.236.178', '82.247.106.95', '207.244.83.218', '162.210.197.55', '185.180.197.65', '31.8.130.8', '114.124.135.2', '46.172.203.108', '185.182.81.41', '199.115.116.37', '207.244.78.175', '207.244.77.139', '185.182.81.85', '172.56.30.213', '79.126.114.90', '5.254.65.114', '207.244.77.9', '103.10.197.202', '87.245.249.103', '185.182.81.48', '39.54.218.203', '109.169.172.138', '39.50.16.30', '89.104.104.227', '78.189.31.17', '207.244.77.19', '95.28.26.67', '39.54.6.166', '145.255.169.92', '176.43.253.71', '185.107.70.202', '65.19.167.131', '199.244.86.149', '197.156.241.249', '114.125.184.172', '89.178.171.173', '151.235.84.235', '185.104.184.120', '197.243.40.75', '88.253.119.59', '103.76.21.243', '207.244.78.50', '95.73.121.206', '185.182.81.60', '176.55.167.228', '179.54.147.13', '156.198.95.108', '199.249.223.63', '165.139.150.133', '185.182.81.16', '185.182.81.80', '162.210.197.54', '41.34.8.12', '86.161.166.126', '103.21.125.80', '5.254.65.15', '65.49.126.73', '69.117.214.158', '92.96.162.204', '64.62.232.66', '2.48.180.82', '213.87.163.155', '108.59.8.217', '91.151.188.194', '197.229.0.32', '76.218.238.42', '178.62.6.233', '159.65.117.243', '217.118.78.80', '109.252.25.1', '96.80.89.69', '89.40.118.87', '185.182.81.25', '73.43.73.161', '108.59.10.184', '5.155.214.63', '103.10.197.195', '95.71.21.143', '113.21.99.50', '198.96.155.3', '203.156.158.201', '5.254.65.19', '103.10.197.133', '207.244.94.5', '190.39.1.149', '103.10.197.61', '213.87.139.175', '91.244.39.229', '136.0.99.204', '77.34.114.167', '185.76.248.253', '185.182.81.139', '207.244.82.154', '199.115.115.194', '139.59.84.23', '209.126.90.78', '156.219.221.191', '109.252.99.3', '67.252.57.173', '222.70.120.196', '207.244.78.47', '156.197.120.27', '185.182.81.76', '78.95.166.34', '103.10.197.131', '37.21.231.95', '87.225.68.121', '46.40.227.14', '77.43.173.56', '114.124.181.244', '37.1.129.188', '128.72.83.20', '5.254.65.85', '31.129.204.120', '5.158.237.18', '151.243.199.70', '185.182.81.77', '103.228.157.94', '69.202.142.68', '94.25.180.120', '185.182.81.91', '103.10.197.154', '202.22.227.26', '49.145.151.70', '207.244.86.198', '185.182.81.19', '185.182.81.69', '5.254.65.123', '65.49.68.203', '103.79.155.58', '216.185.36.99', '80.191.221.21', '5.254.65.220', '91.215.69.212', '5.254.65.24', '103.10.197.204', '105.67.7.89', '195.112.116.163', '46.42.167.129', '190.142.101.84', '207.244.79.152', '5.59.53.95', '14.139.125.241', '197.211.63.74', '195.190.107.166', '185.182.81.135', '194.146.181.131', '83.220.237.252', '41.215.173.33', '142.44.210.206', '62.213.109.218', '199.168.151.35', '5.254.65.217', '45.242.236.74', '80.253.23.149', '185.182.81.11', '93.168.185.76', '185.182.81.82', '77.106.62.60', '185.220.101.20', '185.182.81.47', '185.182.81.56', '5.41.65.151', '66.160.188.43', '74.82.35.71', '79.139.176.23', '88.203.110.34', '64.147.94.201', '213.87.132.49', '91.216.114.201', '179.53.157.148', '185.182.81.4', '196.74.129.52', '95.72.247.249', '185.182.81.71', '185.182.81.138', '154.68.60.100', '81.214.142.169', '147.110.59.244', '200.2.187.239', '68.133.80.57', '5.44.174.110', '142.234.201.129', '89.238.177.226', '120.188.86.112', '207.244.78.173', '173.208.82.162', '115.178.200.218', '139.162.233.190', '43.245.8.67', '103.10.197.58', '207.244.83.219', '148.0.219.242', '5.126.66.228', '37.190.37.137', '182.179.179.160', '103.10.197.220', '41.66.255.100', '37.144.44.196', '207.244.77.18', '5.254.65.102', '213.33.193.34', '185.182.81.51', '154.121.5.242', '92.246.191.120', '186.167.242.158', '217.117.66.54', '85.88.176.70', '114.124.182.15', '146.185.177.103', '179.180.67.5', '207.154.232.214', '91.192.70.25', '156.38.35.15', '147.135.254.228', '103.10.197.130', '195.214.140.20', '31.29.217.147', '73.170.68.18', '142.234.201.141', '2.191.76.162', '151.80.36.117', '5.254.65.195', '213.87.225.138', '5.0.249.218', '27.68.68.184', '178.59.189.246', '95.30.31.106', '213.87.126.137', '104.45.14.157', '196.6.216.5', '185.182.81.131', '5.254.65.177', '103.255.7.21', '212.75.159.112', '103.10.197.196', '217.55.47.233', '109.252.76.112', '36.84.62.52', '185.253.97.52', '31.148.253.33', '185.182.81.78', '159.224.41.242', '46.101.16.232', '5.254.65.97', '89.160.136.97', '207.244.78.8', '5.254.65.82', '185.182.81.92', '95.29.19.127', '185.182.81.22', '66.160.201.58', '93.90.204.172', '2.93.201.96', '182.1.178.122', '148.0.142.65', '94.233.224.122', '163.232.200.115', '200.236.75.164', '106.204.119.26', '168.8.192.22', '185.182.81.83', '107.77.209.106', '207.244.78.17', '89.104.104.224', '106.51.234.22', '71.12.167.41', '188.247.109.2', '213.87.156.209', '192.240.119.59', '78.180.74.219', '37.107.111.54', '103.10.197.132', '5.254.65.8', '105.167.52.122', '146.185.157.173', '95.184.110.95', '23.101.10.145', '5.254.65.124', '151.231.40.224', '178.129.222.227', '185.182.81.68', '185.107.47.215', '146.185.156.139', '120.188.39.56', '176.14.163.226', '178.62.113.166', '95.153.134.122', '185.182.81.75', '156.194.101.98', '185.182.81.72', '182.187.97.214', '41.72.194.58', '196.201.199.210', '185.182.81.79', '51.39.237.115', '202.146.235.80', '176.123.126.254', '86.149.9.202', '41.254.4.43', '91.240.73.248', '185.88.157.231', '171.229.95.88', '5.254.65.129', '139.59.225.74', '95.24.175.100', '5.254.65.182', '185.182.81.50', '89.31.57.5', '129.56.11.18', '207.244.83.104', '199.115.118.85', '89.235.123.202', '154.69.67.5', '36.84.62.49', '146.185.157.38', '31.29.248.93', '109.252.20.82', '207.244.94.36', '66.160.188.67', '5.254.65.6', '38.95.109.110', '178.175.132.67', '103.214.2.35', '196.24.72.24', '185.182.81.9', '109.252.177.102', '136.252.163.99', '185.104.184.116', '162.247.72.199', '213.55.105.3', '5.79.68.161', '188.170.103.189', '5.254.65.21', '88.228.167.196', '41.242.138.49', '103.10.197.59', '178.73.220.45', '200.82.249.248', '5.254.65.107', '207.244.77.172', '5.254.65.84', '37.190.37.197', '213.87.131.60', '37.112.229.42', '95.24.91.228', '185.182.81.84', '77.247.181.162', '78.81.231.143', '185.182.81.46', '207.244.83.114', '41.253.39.240', '92.50.223.44', '173.208.82.164', '41.85.161.178', '213.87.122.199', '37.52.183.88', '207.244.72.201', '109.252.53.106', '108.59.8.208', '104.129.18.10', '122.57.37.39', '176.59.48.37', '125.178.76.189', '154.130.48.206', '113.169.71.251', '91.215.69.23', '54.36.105.8', '95.10.207.189', '128.31.0.13', '81.211.123.74', '103.10.197.13', '46.242.10.245', '81.131.164.246', '156.194.244.214', '178.62.106.169', '204.85.191.31', '207.244.86.200', '77.27.69.166', '192.96.205.131', '139.59.3.30', '80.252.16.20', '185.182.81.137', '150.100.253.6', '103.25.72.234', '207.244.86.195', '154.160.16.103', '78.95.6.2', '185.182.81.44', '197.248.213.18', '202.142.79.94', '38.95.108.247', '2.135.158.83', '37.73.82.56', '103.255.6.75', '5.254.65.110', '64.62.175.68', '207.244.83.209', '172.241.114.173', '207.244.79.137', '207.244.82.251', '207.244.86.232', '94.233.224.26', '174.141.115.146', '109.174.112.128', '93.91.80.6', '41.190.3.77', '159.89.115.182', '188.163.3.226', '95.191.226.57', '139.5.154.162', '193.0.219.72', '185.182.81.70', '138.197.174.51', '41.217.109.25', '39.50.91.154', '37.204.198.46', '130.180.218.30', '5.254.65.17', '138.197.160.42', '5.254.65.187', '37.195.213.64', '188.170.73.65', '197.48.231.108', '185.189.113.42', '185.182.81.74', '41.66.203.243', '163.21.7.42', '5.254.65.83', '157.50.236.233', '94.233.224.7', '128.71.22.17', '130.34.246.190', '185.52.141.42', '139.59.84.2', '84.241.202.178', '123.242.160.17', '74.82.17.52', '182.0.205.139', '203.202.229.194', '89.238.191.150', '79.165.225.194', '73.61.8.75', '41.254.8.167', '185.182.81.5', '94.47.16.26', '182.186.238.234', '156.216.204.96', '109.252.57.81', '180.252.104.52', '79.148.109.242', '66.160.201.47', '2.191.110.236', '207.244.77.13', '5.254.65.98', '145.255.166.214', '159.203.130.12', '197.234.221.77', '159.89.206.211', '85.141.69.27', '185.182.81.90', '77.31.101.152', '202.22.237.40', '95.221.205.237', '207.244.77.55', '104.236.233.75', '5.254.65.104', '104.236.233.182', '103.10.197.60', '103.10.197.222', '182.54.141.154', '138.197.174.79', '176.33.136.50', '185.182.81.10', '185.220.101.30', '94.138.40.2', '41.44.178.2', '196.207.121.147', '213.138.86.113', '31.173.83.65', '199.115.115.197', '46.72.89.106', '103.240.170.209', '5.254.65.215', '146.185.171.157', '185.182.81.57', '188.119.59.75', '46.164.104.176', '176.52.96.95', '207.244.83.99', '31.43.31.116', '178.62.208.24', '5.254.65.167', '185.182.81.73', '104.194.24.250', '79.200.158.58', '79.111.52.85', '103.10.197.91', '199.249.224.65', '5.136.175.48', '111.119.165.253', '216.218.222.12', '191.248.209.198', '5.254.65.81', '178.46.97.50', '27.97.248.46', '190.72.126.220', '178.140.204.131', '5.114.82.81', '118.175.154.120', '207.244.90.69', '185.182.81.7', '103.17.88.247', '108.248.141.54', '130.34.246.189', '207.244.79.154', '41.66.255.247', '128.69.14.62', '87.107.208.172', '199.115.116.35', '46.191.213.221', '199.115.114.220', '172.56.44.234', '69.12.94.91', '5.254.65.99', '37.203.243.97', '185.182.81.29', '37.210.142.211', '207.244.78.9', '206.189.56.39', '193.104.27.86', '37.190.37.236', '112.197.34.56', '189.124.82.209', '99.66.132.171', '5.254.65.16', '46.201.114.83', '81.31.178.23', '94.47.97.98', '82.102.31.251', '103.10.197.203', '94.98.252.208', '14.139.160.236', '185.182.81.130', '184.43.6.218', '92.37.143.180', '5.254.65.12', '83.142.185.126', '5.254.65.178', '213.87.123.37', '36.67.214.132', '185.182.81.21', '205.164.32.216', '207.244.83.198', '5.254.65.11', '197.210.221.42', '207.244.83.206', '5.254.65.130', '176.14.156.125', '94.138.40.7', '182.75.59.110', '162.210.197.57', '41.35.98.90', '95.139.11.104', '103.10.197.93', '39.40.168.95', '213.87.127.74', '2.94.25.98', '216.218.222.14', '207.244.82.155', '138.197.154.118', '199.249.223.69', '5.254.65.112', '62.120.19.197', '185.182.81.17', '148.0.140.9', '103.10.197.197', '185.182.81.15', '217.114.239.64', '185.182.81.134', '130.180.217.17', '111.88.82.111', '112.210.165.48', '81.92.200.142', '185.182.81.43', '207.244.77.3', '169.159.85.133', '5.254.65.20', '197.234.221.34', '192.162.242.11', '185.182.81.67', '103.247.48.9', '109.173.73.174', '171.25.193.20', '207.244.77.17', '176.59.44.162', '95.28.48.169', '5.254.65.113', '62.112.114.74', '5.254.65.174', '179.96.223.197', '149.202.202.78', '146.185.157.243', '110.93.216.238', '217.148.214.162', '23.100.15.206', '24.133.136.29', '59.189.57.53', '185.182.81.62', '31.181.90.52', '5.254.65.117', '94.99.170.144', '146.185.157.164', '178.62.230.201', '41.223.117.58', '197.54.177.15', '212.252.67.30', '109.252.86.175', '194.146.149.39', '207.244.83.197', '190.94.3.236', '207.244.94.9', '5.254.65.193', '5.254.65.194', '207.244.77.10', '146.185.158.9', '5.254.65.172', '37.156.22.79', '209.190.17.22', '103.10.197.156', '5.254.65.9', '178.140.62.96', '207.244.77.16', '109.161.121.117', '37.78.31.88', '185.220.101.13', '185.182.81.87', '87.107.165.5', '185.135.233.14', '209.58.148.100', '83.110.13.200', '5.254.65.132', '93.80.234.243', '190.39.198.140', '95.221.183.242', '185.222.209.32', '154.160.16.167', '80.71.249.236', '185.182.81.39', '41.79.197.12', '91.76.89.93', '45.247.206.86', '185.182.81.88', '192.81.222.95', '207.244.86.236', '197.210.29.171', '213.61.95.74', '41.254.7.18', '31.9.55.66', '154.112.8.183', '5.254.65.180', '37.187.158.97', '195.149.108.45', '94.179.147.128', '94.130.206.211', '31.173.85.237', '103.10.197.221', '46.39.83.173', '5.254.65.170', '5.254.65.18', '95.167.31.202', '207.244.83.212', '138.197.174.132', '185.182.81.35', '192.96.205.135', '130.88.240.92', '185.182.81.94', '90.147.2.94', '209.126.90.97', '128.75.107.209', '2.94.139.161', '103.106.174.102', '186.4.212.26', '37.145.142.85', '207.244.86.194', '72.211.60.177', '95.30.45.134', '80.71.253.200', '5.254.65.109', '185.182.81.38', '5.254.65.214', '178.62.221.111', '81.92.200.204', '89.104.104.226', '95.73.236.188', '207.244.83.113', '185.182.81.24', '103.247.48.111', '176.59.43.149', '109.233.172.188', '207.244.70.35', '84.17.230.179', '83.123.148.16', '122.171.168.163', '213.87.121.217', '110.54.232.113', '206.189.56.10', '154.160.30.129', '207.244.93.227', '178.46.96.130', '87.116.196.230', '181.208.250.104', '43.252.233.33', '207.244.82.249', '154.68.5.60', '37.27.72.154', '178.68.165.3', '194.186.9.228', '207.244.79.134', '41.34.209.13', '192.119.160.242', '37.187.129.166', '41.254.7.152', '46.38.23.226', '185.182.81.52', '27.34.104.88', '31.29.253.114', '200.17.141.3', '86.62.75.82', '93.183.219.225', '94.143.40.157', '103.10.197.194', '188.166.212.116', '185.182.81.2', '212.98.135.186', '103.10.197.92', '207.244.83.195', '217.64.17.124', '46.242.10.244', '209.58.136.236', '156.203.226.215', '103.10.197.218', '199.115.114.218', '185.182.81.8', '207.244.82.231', '95.8.0.20', '207.244.82.133', '128.74.124.28', '111.95.14.210', '213.87.126.35', '5.254.65.134', '91.240.210.185', '185.182.81.132', '95.32.139.134', '213.55.110.157', '185.182.81.26', '176.47.67.182', '91.65.54.25', '217.10.34.243', '185.182.81.133', '182.1.191.230', '103.10.197.90', '213.87.225.153', '207.244.77.184', '185.182.81.81', '5.254.65.88', '123.176.6.58', '213.55.110.206', '93.157.169.12', '103.10.197.219', '109.252.81.16', '78.111.187.63', '82.196.1.179', '185.182.81.59', '148.0.193.199', '14.202.100.66', '5.250.37.110', '156.219.245.39', '31.9.112.197', '185.112.37.25', '128.70.176.120', '185.182.81.27', '188.226.226.40', '109.174.113.45', '5.246.33.162', '5.254.65.189', '46.151.246.57', '77.71.24.206', '178.62.36.218', '185.182.81.36', '196.188.112.153', '199.249.223.49', '80.252.153.74', '87.109.169.79', '207.244.83.200', '197.210.54.144', '95.57.231.156', '207.244.94.33', '103.16.25.2', '217.174.233.46', '178.184.98.116', '185.182.81.55', '107.77.207.197', '86.21.86.205', '5.254.65.192', '38.95.108.230', '94.13.131.173', '107.77.209.181', '176.59.54.71', '128.179.252.54', '31.215.58.51', '207.244.83.123', '85.106.69.110', '192.160.102.170', '37.146.34.208', '46.39.228.226', '87.225.75.186', '159.89.123.60', '176.59.68.249', '37.143.20.94', '105.112.29.37', '89.146.74.31', '90.147.2.86', '217.144.175.138', '212.252.57.203', '131.117.162.145', '109.63.245.141', '92.97.199.104', '176.123.121.221', '213.142.154.3', '180.160.55.195', '176.195.133.16', '172.241.112.3', '207.244.83.217', '125.167.120.44', '109.252.85.9', '46.39.53.115', '206.189.201.4', '31.173.83.78', '199.115.115.215', '178.62.153.200']
```

How do I convert a list of ips like above into a list of subnets?

For example;

`185.182.0.0/y, 207.244.0.0/x`

**Edit**

I'm getting a lot of malicious traffic from several ips that look like they're in the same subnet, however there are a few thousand ips, how do I convert a list like this into subnets so that I can block the subnet?

Comment: Please post your desired output.

Comment: /32 only contains one ip right?

Comment: Why so quick to downvote?? How does this help anyone??

Comment: Downvotes are likely due to poorly the formatted question. You really should follow the posting guidance on SO found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I'm getting a lot of malicious traffic from several ips that look like they're in the same subnet, however there are a few thousand ips, how do I convert a list like this into subnets so that I can block the subnet?

Comment: I understand your problem, but not the conditioning of the data. You've shown us the list of ips, but that just a comma separated grouping of strings. How are you storing these malicious ips? Are they line separated on a file? Are they stored in a JSON structure? Once you answer that, we can answer how to build a list for you.

Comment: Well like SparkleGoat said, /32 is a single IP, so if all your subnetted IPs end in /32 that won't help you much. Try looking into ipaddress module in python, as mentioned in this stackoverflow post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29542393/6121503

Comment: They're stored as a JSON array in a file.

Comment: Post an example of the JSON (an entire object is preferred) and somebody will be able to help you.

Comment: @pstatix I've removed the /32 and posted the original data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer by Wang is the correct way to do this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45503187/3176550

```
list_of_ips = ['10.0.0.0', '10.0.0.1', '10.0.0.2', '10.0.0.3', '10.0.0.5']
import ipaddress
nets = [ipaddress.ip_network(_ip) for _ip in list_of_ips]
cidrs = ipaddress.collapse_addresses(nets)
list(cidrs)
Out[6]: [IPv4Network('10.0.0.0/30'), IPv4Network('10.0.0.5/32')]
```

Answer (score 2):

Im guessing subnets are `000.000.XXX.XXX` where the `X's` can be a single `0`?

Lets assume you have:

```
ban = ['162.210.197.58/32', '36.72.31.198/34', ..., '134.35.42.49/20', '176.65.117.81/32']
```

Use a set comprehension to ensure you get only unique elements:

```
subnets = {'.'.join(addr.split('.')[:2]) + '.0.0/' + addr.split('/')[-1] for addr in ban}
```

And you get:

```
>>> subnets
{'162.210.0.0/32', '36.72.0.0/34', ..., '134.35.0.0/20'}
```

Comment: What about the `/xx` range at the end? I don't know what that value should be?

Comment: @Jonathan You dont have that in your example for the addresses in the `ban` variable. Do you store the `/xx` at the end? You mentioned they are stored in JSON, but your example doesn't show that.

Comment: All I have is the exact list of ips posted in the question, I noticed a lot of repetitiveness since a lot of them seem to be from the same subnet. What I'm trying to do is instead of blocking 50+ ips from the same subnet to block the whole subnet instead, which would be cleaner.

Comment: Johnathan that all depends on how many ips you want to filter. These blocks are separated and are registered to different organizations. You could look up each one to get the cider that belongs to the org or you can just use /24 but that may only block a subset of the organizations ips. There are also ban list by country that are already compiled that you can use as well.

Comment: @Jonathan I will note that I am not familiar with subnet formats or representation in string form, so I'm only able to work on what you provide me with!

Comment: Thanks @pstatix I'm not familiar with it also hence my confusion, the set comprehension takes me part of the way, I'll just find what the appropriate cidr should be and append it to the output.

Comment: Yeah so if you are blocking individually and need a cidr then /32 should do.

Answer (score 2):

Note that an IPv4 subnet may be many different sizes, from `/32` for a single IP address to `/0` for the whole internet. You don't have enough information to work out how a network administrator has subnetted their network if the only thing you have is an IP address. Assuming a `/24` or a `/16` will often be wrong.

That said, you *could* use whois to lookup the net ranges associated with the ASNs which contain particular IP addresses. You could use whois from python via a tool like [ipwhois](https://pypi.org/project/ipwhois/) to build up a list of net ranges that you consider "bad" based on the fact that you've had a contact from a bad IP in that ASN.

```
from ipwhois import IPWhois

bad_ips = ["185.182.81.12",]
bad_asn_ranges = set()

for ip in bad_ips:
    obj = IPWhois(ip)
    ret = obj.lookup_whois()
    print(ret)
    bad_asn_ranges.add(ret['asn_cidr'])

print(bad_asn_ranges)
```

This would have unintended consequences if good people and bad people both coexist on the same ASN as one another.

Comment: Since the first 2 parts seem to be the repeated ones, I'm thinking `/16` might actually work? Running the above gives `185.182.80.0/22` but I have about 96 starting with `185.182.81`

Comment: `/16` will work after a fashion, in that it will block lots of nearby addresses probably including other bad addresses. But it will usually have the unintended consequence of blocking people in nearby ASNs who are not related to the bad people except they had the bad luck to be assigned a nearby address range. So the `/16` approach would eventually cause large unrelated chunks of the internet to stop working.

Comment: Actually, if I do `import ipaddress; ipaddress.IPv4Address('185.182.81.12') in ipaddress.IPv4Network('185.182.80.0/22');` it returns true, meaning this ip is correctly identified as being in this organisation's assigned ip range. I think this is the best and most complete solution for what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

If IP addresses are stored as a list and are in a string type, here is one very simple solution to reseting all subnets and then at the same time leave duplicates in another condition. Maybe slow code, but functional code.

```
data = ['162.210.197.58', '36.72.121.146', '36.72.121.4', '162.210.108.4', '190.5.140.90']

tmp = []
for ip in data:
    ip1, ip2, ip3, ip4 = ip.split('.')
    if (ip1 + '.' + ip2 + '.0.0') not in tmp:
        tmp.append(ip1 + '.' + ip2 + '.0.0')
data = tmp

print(data)
```

Another example:

```
data = ['162.210.197.58', '36.72.121.146', '36.72.121.4', '162.210.108.4', '190.5.140.90']

msk = 1   # range 1-3, how much bytes do you want set to zero, from right side (in IP address)
tmp = []
for ip in data:
    s = '.'.join(ip.split('.')[:-msk]) + ('.0'*msk)   # split the string by '.' delimiter, then combine all to back but without msk entries from the right side, then add string '.0' repeated msk times
    if s not in tmp:
        tmp.append(s)
data = tmp

print(data)
```

A note:

It is better to keep IP addresses as an integer data type (as Python does not know the Byte data type). Then any IP address operations will be really simple and fast. Logical operations NOR, XOR, OR, AND, etc. (as needed), you could do everything you need in a professional area of computer networks using a mask. Of course, it depends on the length of the addressable IP address field - as the colleagues mentioned above. If the length of the standard most frequently used is 16 bits (2 bytes) or 24 bits (3 bytes), then my code is sufficient. However, if the length in the bits is non-standard (26 bits, 12 bits, 10 bits, etc.), then it is better to set the integer type from the string IP address and further process the IP addresses already as IPv4 length estimates, which are 4 bytes operations XOR, AND, OR, ...).

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the 24 bit prefixes and number of occurrences.  `defaultdict` is used to automatically insert a `0` in the dictionary when the key is missing, making the code more simple.

```
data = ['162.210.197.58', '36.72.31.198'] #etc....

import collections
subnets = collections.defaultdict(int)

for ip in data:
   subnets[".".join(ip.split('.')[0:3])] += 1

print(subnets)
```

Comment: I get output that looks like `defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {'162.210.197': 5, '36.72.31': 1})`. Also the /24 isn't a requirement I'm not sure what it should be. I've edited the question.

Comment: @Jonathan, you haven't made it clear what subnets you are looking for.  You either need to pre-define the subnets and then add each ip address to the pre-defined subnet, or pick a standard prefix length you are after, and let the program identify them..  My example uses /24 (or it could use /16 just as easy). There is no "easy" way to solve this data problem.  In a practical side, how about just putting rate limiting on your server?